# SwiftUI - failed to produce diagnostic for expression

Tags: debugging, swiftui

I am making a sign app project, this error code appears in one of my file, which is PrayerView, and I have fixed other errors appeared in Xcode project, but this error cannot find a way to fix.. here is the file code:

```
//
//  PrayerView.swift

import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct PrayerView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: PrayerViewModel
    @ObservedObject var lotViewModel: LotViewModel
    
    init(container: NSPersistentContainer) {
        lotViewModel = LotViewModel(container: container)
        viewModel = PrayerViewModel(lotViewModel: lotViewModel)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            // 顯示抽籤結果
            if viewModel.lotNumber != 0 {
                LotView(viewModel: viewModel.lotViewModel) // 在此處添加 LotView
                    .padding()
                
                // 問題種類選擇器
                Picker(selection: $viewModel.selectedCategory, label: Text("問題種類")) {
                    Text("願望").tag("願望")
                    Text("疾病").tag("疾病")
                    Text("盼望的人").tag("盼望的人")
                    Text("遺失物").tag("遺失物")
                    Text("搬家").tag("搬家")
                    Text("蓋新居").tag("蓋新居")
                    Text("嫁娶").tag("嫁娶")
                    Text("交往").tag("交往")
                    Text("旅行").tag("旅行")
                    Text("結親緣").tag("結親緣")
                        .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
                }
                // 隨喜功德解籤按鈕
                NavigationLink(destination: PaymentView(viewModel: viewModel.paymentViewModel)) {
                    Text("隨喜功德解籤")
                }
                .padding()
            } else {
                Button(action: {
                    viewModel.drawLot()
                }, label: {
                    Text("抽籤")
                })
                .padding()
            }
            
                .background(
                    NavigationLink(
                        destination: ResultView(viewModel: ResultViewModel(lotViewModel: lotViewModel)),
                        tag: true,
                        selection: $viewModel.shouldShowResult?) {
                            EmptyView()
                        }
                        .hidden()
                )
        }
    }
}

struct PrayerView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "MyAppDataModel")
        container.loadPersistentStores { _, error in
            if let error = error {
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error)")
            }
        }
        return PrayerView(container: container)
    }
}
```

It is a view file, with a LotView display on it, with a button to drawlot in LotViewModel, with a button to pay and then jump to ResultView..

Comment: Needs a [mre] to be debuggable here.

Comment: Observations: it seems you are using nested `ObservableObject`, this is not a good idea. You also try to create `viewModel = PrayerViewModel(...)` in `init()`, this will give you the error: `self used before all stored properties are initialized`. The `failed to produce diagnostic for expression` error, is because of the `if/else` and using `.background(...)` on it.
The result of the `if/else` does not take a `.background(...)` modifier. So re-organise your code.

Comment: Try removing the view model objects and use the View struct as designed. In SwiftUI the View struct holds the view data so it already is the view model.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine thank you for your comment. You are right, the .background(…) caused the error code stated in the title. Thank you so much.. I don’t know how to correct the rest that you mentioned.. and after correcting .background(…), i have difficulties in loading the PrayerView, it just shows the “抽籤”button, and when I press the button, the app crashes..it seems that the init process crashed, how to modify it?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the view model objects and use the `View` struct as designed. In SwiftUI the `View` struct holds the view data so it already is the view model, e.g.

```
struct PrayerView: View {
    //@ObservedObject var viewModel: PrayerViewModel
    //@ObservedObject var lotViewModel: LotViewModel
    
    //init(container: NSPersistentContainer) {
    //    lotViewModel = LotViewModel(container: container)
    //    viewModel = PrayerViewModel(lotViewModel: lotViewModel)
    //}

    let lotNumber: Int
    @State var selectedCategory: Category?
    
    var body: some View {
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but PrayerView needs functions and information stored in PrayerViewModel.swift and LotViewModel.swift files, what should I do？